Can I reduce the number of frames batch processed by "parser" element before being sent through the rest of the GStreamer pipeline?
I have C code listening to key events that will update the value of "framerate" in the parser element when a certain key is pressed.
Here are my pipeline elements (linked in this order):
data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("gstreamer-stream-pipeline");
data.source  = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "source");
data.parser = gst_element_factory_make ("rawvideoparse", "parser");
data.converter = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "converter");
data.encoder  = gst_element_factory_make ("vp8enc", "encoder");
data.muxer = gst_element_factory_make ("webmmux", "muxer");
data.sink = gst_element_factory_make ("tcpclientsink", "video-sink");


Here is the line of code making the change:
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (data->parser), "framerate", (int) data-> newFrameRate, 1, NULL);

There is a delay of about 4 seconds between when this change is made and the resulting video output reflecting this change. When the framerate is doubled, that delay turns into 2 seconds. This leads me to believe there is something in the "rawvideoparse" element that is batching the reads from the file, and then once it completes parsing that batch, will use the new settings for the next batch.
I have a different implementation of this using different sink elements and no "rawvideoparse" (speed is adjusted using the sink in that version), and the key events take effect instantly, so I know it is not a timing issue between the key listener and the pipeline.
Is there a way to specify the size of the chunks being processed? I would like to get this to a place where it parses .25 seconds at a time before sending it through the pipeline.
